# Fantasy (Novel/Novelette?) ... witches, a witch-hunter, a roller coaster, and a potted plant

Tags: story-identification, urban-fantasy, witches

Just fragments, I'm afraid; I think this is from the '70s. One of those "witches in modern times" things, in a world where ordinary people don't know there are witches.
I recall they worked in an office, that there were male and female witches. One of the male witches urinated into a potted plant, which later turned (sentient? carnivorous?). There is the villain, a witch-hunter, perhaps puritan. And I'm fairly certain that there was, at the climax, a scene on a roller-coaster.
Not Tom Holt's Portable Door, btw, nor Pratchett/Gaiman.

Comment: I'm sure I've read this but I'm damned if I can remember the title. As I recall it was a regular 9 to 5 office, but the employees were witches. I forget what the company did. I think the plant got urinated on after an office party.

Comment: @JohnRennie, I recall it's being after an office party as well ... also the  'regular 9-5 office' ... maybe advertising?